# SharePoint-online AD Groups with Yammer and Calendars

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer

I am confused about the relationship between AD groups and Yammer and Group Calendars. I have a SP with 6 functional groups (let's call them A,B,C etc). Each group needs a group calendar and a group "discussion" area.

I am only using modern pages in my SP site. I want to create a Yammer group and a group calendar for each functional. I want (if possible) to set up a group in AD for each functional area and map these to the Yammer group and a group calendar.

If I create a Yammer group will that automatically create an AD group, or should I create an AD group first and then assign it to a Yammer group?

Same with calendars. In a SP I have a group calendar for group A, and want to assign that to this group and allow them to overlay it with their Exchange calendars.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 will spin up several common services based on what you create.

If you create a SharePoint site, you'll automatically get an O365 Group, a Planner Plan, a Power BI workspace. (but not Team)

If you create a Team, you'll automatically get an O365 Group, Planner Plan, Power BI Workspace, and a SharePoint site.

The O365 Group will contain the members and those groups are given access to those services.  You will see that O365 group appear in Azure AD and the group gives you a Shared Mailbox and Calendar.

You should be able to use the email address created for your O365 group to grant those users access to a Yammer group and now you'll have a single place to manage that group's permissions.

Comment: Jason, this is good, if unfortunate, information. It seems to me that this is all backwards. Shouldn't I be able to create a SP site and THEN assign groups to it? What if I create a SharePoint site and then want to associate it with a Team? [which is one of the things I might want to do]. It seems once you go down a certain path then you are out of luck.

Comment: You get the group automatically but you are still able to create your own. The auto created group is more of a convenience. In your case, your site will have a group that shares the same name as your site, and you can give that group permission to your Team. It's basically an AD group.